# Sending emails with commands in python

Tags: python, email

Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't send the emails. I don't get any error when it doesn't sent. Is there a limit or time I have to wait before sending another email?

Example Code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

if cmd == "emailA":
              # Define email addresses to use
              addr_to   = 'toEmail'
              addr_from = 'fromEmail'
              # Define SMTP email server details
              smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
              smtp_user   = 'myEmail'
              smtp_pass   = 'pass'
              s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,587)
              s.starttls()
              # Construct email
              msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
              msg['To'] = addr_to
              msg['From'] = addr_from
              msg['Subject'] = 'Subject #1'
              # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
              text = "Subject #1"
              message = """\
              <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                Subject #1
                </body>
              </html>
                </body>
              </html>
              """
              part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
              part2 = MIMEText(message, 'html')
              msg.attach(part1)
              msg.attach(part2)

              s.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
              s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
              s.quit()

if cmd == "emailB":
              # Define email addresses to use
              addr_to   = 'toEmail'
              addr_from = 'fromEmail'
              # Define SMTP email server details
              smtp_server = 'smtp.gmail.com'
              smtp_user   = 'myEmail'
              smtp_pass   = 'pass'
              s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,587)
              s.starttls()
              # Construct email
              msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
              msg['To'] = addr_to
              msg['From'] = addr_from
              msg['Subject'] = 'Subject #2'
              # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
              text = "Subject #2"
              message = """\
              <html>
                <head></head>
                <body>
                Subject #2
                </body>
              </html>
                </body>
              </html>
              """
              part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
              part2 = MIMEText(message, 'html')
              msg.attach(part1)
              msg.attach(part2)

              s.login(smtp_user,smtp_pass)
              s.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg.as_string())
              s.quit()
```

I want to send emails using commands Eg. !emailA

Comment: Have you tried to use some [network analyzer](https://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the traffic between your application and the SMTP server ? That way, you could exactly pin-point the problem.

Comment: @Sylvain no, i don't have any experience with network analyzers. I am new to programing. what would be the best smtp server to use? other than gmail. any recommendations?